# Confusion about synchronous socket in ZeroMQ

Tags: asynchronous, zeromq, synchronous

This may appear as a silly question, but I am really confused about the terminology of the ZeroMQ regarding synchronous sockets like [`REQ` and `REP`](http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:chapter3#Recap-of-Request-Reply-Sockets).

By my understanding a synchronous communication occurs when a client sends a message an then it blocks, until the response arrives. If ZeroMQ implemented a synchronous communication then only a `.send()` method would be enough for a synchronous socket.

I think that synchronous sockets terminology of ZeroMQ refers only to the inability of sending more messages until the response of the last message arrives, but the "sender" can still continue its processing ( doing more stuff ) asynchronously.

Is this true?

In that case, is there any straightforward way to implement a synchronous communication using ZeroMQ?

**EDIT**: Synchronous communication makes sense when I want to invoke a method in a remote process (like RPC). If I want to execute a series of commands in a remote process and each command needs the result of the previous one to do its job then asynchronous communication is not the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use ZMQ for implementing a synchronous framework, you can very nearly do it using just ZMQ; you can set the high water mark to 1. Unfortunately that's not quite it; what you want is an out going queue length of 0. Even more unfortunately, setting the high water mark to 0 is interpretted by ZMQ as infinity...

So the only option is to implement a synchronous transfer protocol on top of ZMQ. That's not very difficult to do. The conversation between the two ends will be something like "can I send?", "yes you can send now", "ok here it is", "ok I have received it" (both ends return to caller) (or at least the programatic version of that). This sets up what is called an execution rendevous - both ends know that they both reached a certain point of execution.

Technically speaking what you're doing is taking ZeroMQ (Actor Model) and turning it into something more like Communicating Sequential Processes.

**RPC**

Having said all that, from your edit I think you might like to consider [Cap'n Proto](https://capnproto.org/). This is a C++ serialisation technology that has a neat RPC trick. If the return from one RPC call is the input to another, you can chain those all together somehow in advance (see [here](https://capnproto.org/rpc.html)).

Answer (score 1):

### Let's start with a first step
forget everything you know about sockets.

ZeroMQ is more a concept of thinking about distributed-systems ( multi-agent like ) and how to design a software, with a use of such a smart signalling / messaging framework.

This is the core aim of the ZeroMQ, to allow designers remain thinking in the application domain and let all the low level dirty work to be operated actually without much of the designers' need to care of.

If have just recently started with ZeroMQ, one may enjoy a [short **read about a ZeroMQ global view first**,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46615141/how-to-control-the-source-ip-address-of-a-zeromq-packet-on-a-machine-with-multip/46620571#46620571) before discussing details.

Having read and understood the concept of the ZeroMQ hierarchy, it is way simpler to start on details:

- given a local **`Context()`** instance is a data-pumping engine and having a **`REQ/REP`** Scalable Formal Communications Archetype pattern in mind, the story is now actually a story about a network of distributed-Finite-State-Automata.
- local process, operating just one side of the distributed `REQ/REP` communication archetype has zero power to influence the remote process to receive or not the message that was passed from the local process over to the ZeroMQ delivery services towards the indended recipient(s) in a fair belief. The less the local process can influence the remote process' intent to respond at all or not, so welcome to the realms of distributed multi-agent games.

Both the **`REQ`** and the **`REP`** formal behaviour has to meet its both the { local | distributed-mode }-expected sort of behaviour -- `REQ` asks first, `REP` answers then, so as to keep the contracted promise. The point is, that this behaviour is distributed and split among a pair of nodes, plus there are cases, when network incidents may throw the distributed-FSA into an unsalvageable mutual deadlock ( one may find more posts on this here [zeromq](/questions/tagged/zeromq) quite often ).

So, your local-side `REQ` code imperatively `.send()`-s and has no obligation to stop without doing anything reasonable until `REP`-side `.recv( zmq.NOBLOCK )`-s or not ( no one has any kind of warranty a remote node exists at all, similarly, one has to set oneselves ready to anticipate and handle all cases, where a remote side will never respond, so many "new" challenges appear from the nature of a distributed multi-agent ecosystem ).

There are smart ways to handle this new breed of distributed chaos and uncertainties, using, best using `.poll()` and non-blocking forms of either the `.send()` and `.recv()`-methods, as these let user-code to remain capable of handling all expected and un-expected events in due time and fashion.

One may also operate rather many co-existent ZeroMQ connections, so as to prioritise and specialise each and any form of the multi-agents' interactions in a distributed system design, even for designing in fault-resilience and similar high-level robustness concept, where asynchronous nature of each of the interactions avoids a need of any sort of coordination or synchronisation with a remote (  possibly even not yet present ) agent, which is principally an autonomous entity, having it's own domain of control, so again, being principally asynchronous to what local-side agent might "expect", the less "influence" in any other form but by an attempt to send "there" a message "telegram".

### So yes,
ZeroMQ is asynchronous brokerless signalling / messaging framework.

For *(almost)* synchronous communications, one may take steps and measures to trim down the ( principally distributed ) asynchronous control loops -- best update your post with an MCVE example and details about what are your particular goals for being achieved.