# About ZeroMQ and polling on non-blocking sockets :

Tags: c++, sockets, zeromq, distributed-computing, polling

In Linux, if an application uses raw non-blocking sockets for reading, in conjunction with poll, will it be possible to be notified when a socket has some data available for reading or not?

I tried to dig into ZeroMQ documentation, but I cannot find my way.

I found the flag **`ZMQ_NOBLOCK`**, but it is applied when called **`zmq_recv`**.

Is there a way to set the socket itself as Non-Blocking so that poll can return immediately if there is nothing to read?

I am using C++ as language for my app.

Answer (score 4):

### Well, there are few missed points here:

First, a ZeroMQ-`Socket`-instance is not anything like an O/S socket. For principal disambiguation, feel free to read posts on conceptual differences.

This is an often re-articulated misconception, so let me repeat it in bold.

**Beware:** ZeroMQ `Socket()`-instance is **not** a tcp-socket-as-you-know-it. Best read about the main conceptual differences in [ [**ZeroMQ hierarchy** in **less than a five seconds**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/46620571/3666197) ] or [other posts and discussions **here**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D)

---

### The `ZMQ_NOBLOCK` symbol can be used in more places:

the `zmq_recv()` being one such, `zmq_send()` being another.

This symbol is principaly **`#define`**-ed in header file, but somewhere having also some other value-identical aliases, a **`zmq.DONTWAIT`** being one such **`flag`**-composition related symbol for python-wrappers/bindings.

---

### The **`Socket`**-instance has no such property as (not-)being blocking:

this is the core principal miss in your so far posted questions.

The `Socket`-instance does not persist any such feature per-se.

The respective ( individual ) instance operation - a call to a **`{ .recv() | .send() }`**-method can use a parameter-based mechanism to change it's per-call modus operandi:
**`flags = { 0, ZMQ_DONTWAIT, ZMQ_SENDMORE, ZMQ_DONTWAIT && ZMQ_SENDMORE }`**
but having no such option to "turn"-any-such mode on/off to persist.

---

### Q: "*Is there a way to set the socket itself as Non-Blocking*"?
A: No.

---

### Q: "*Is there a way to set the `Poller.poll()` to return immediately*"?
A: YES!

> `int zmq_poll ( zmq_pollitem_t *items, int nitems,` **`long timeout`** `);`

so,
unless one calls **`zmq_poll( ..., -1 )`**, which turns the polling hang indefinitely long, the `zmq_poll()`-call returns as late as `timeout` **`[ms]`**, so using `timeout == 0`, the `zmq_poll()`-call returns immediately, whether there has been found any item or not, **that's great**, isn't it?