# How many bytes are used for longer string when sending via ZMQ?

Tags: zeromq, distributed-system, pyzmq, jeromq

I'm using ZeroMQ / ZMQ from Python and Java and have a question. When sending a shorter string, ZMQ uses one byte as described here (http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#A-Minor-Note-on-Strings)

> Then what goes onto the wire is a length (one byte for shorter
>   strings) and the string contents as individual characters.

Does anyone know how many bytes are used when sending a longer string?

Comment: i think this describes the format (https://rfc.zeromq.org/spec:15/ZMTP/)

Answer (score 0):

> *How many bytes are used for longer string when sending via ZMQ?*

### That depends on hell more things, than just on the string itself :

Your post refers to indeed historical text - the [zguide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#A-Minor-Note-on-Strings) pages.

While this was sure a very helpful first-read source in the early days of ZeroMQ v.2.x, today, we live with [distributed-sysems](/questions/tagged/distributed-sysems) spanning many versions, from v.2.1+, 3.x, 4.x, 4.2 being so far the last stable API version in 2018-Q2.

No one can a priori guess what API-version was used on the message-sender's side, until a receiver actually sets/accepts the link-setup and **`.recv()`**-s the respective message. Relying on a C-lang based **`s_recv()`**-helper tricks in post v4.0 API is not a sure direction to follow.

Being in python, many protocol-hardwired details remain beyond your sight, yet there are byte-maps, that get filled under the hood exactly as the benevolent dictatorship, indoctrinated in the published ZeroMQ RFC/ZMTP-specifications, dictates.

---

### If we cannot guess or know beforehand, can we ... ?

Yes, we can experiment. Best setup a controlled [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system) experiment.

**Node A :** The Sender
can be pythonic, being a sender:
- setup a **`REQ`**-archetype *AccessNode* <sup>( details in **["ZeroMQ Hierarchy in less than a five seconds"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/46620571/3666197)** )</sup>,
- setup **`.setsockopt( zmq.IDENTITY, ... )`** with a randomness-generated static identity,
- setup a **`.setsockopt( zmq.REQ_RELAXED, 1 )`**,
- **`.bind()`** it to a known endpoint of a transport-class of one's choice
- start an **`xrange()`**-generator controlled **`for L in xrange( 1, int( 1E+9 ) )`**-loop of **`.send()`**-s
- there load a payload **`.send( r"{0:}|{1:}".format( str( L ), L * r"*" ) )`**
- handle the respective `.recv()` for a REP-side "answer",
- check the error-states and adapt the `time.sleep()`-s / re-loops, according to the sender-side socket capacity and capability to send further payloads

**Node B :** The Receiver | The MitM-sniffer
ought be as low level as possible, so as to dis-assemble the RFC/ZMTP wire-line protocol, so python gets out of the candidate list. Other option may include a wire-level sniffer(s), if the selected transport-class permits ( an `ipc://` or a `vmci://` one will not )

- setup a **`ROUTER`**-archetype AccessNode,
- **`.connect()`** it to the know Node A's transport-class endpoint used,
- start `.recv()`-ing messages,

If your experiment has correctly acquired / sniffed the wire-level details about the ZMTP-compliant transport sizes of the know payload compositions, your question gets repeatable, verifiable, quantitatively correct records on **`string`**-size to message-size mapping-function.

**A BONUS POINT:  for those indeed interested . . .**
Next,
 re-run the controlled white-box [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system) experiment above,
 now with having the **Node A: The Sender**-side extended it's behaviour to also
{ randomly | deterministically } { change | alter } its own configuration
 ( or map both such options onto a pair of the same payload re-`.send()`-s )
with a
**`.setsockopt( zmq.REQ_CORRELATE, { on | off } )`**
 inside its **`for`**-loop and record the observed changes in the expected outputs.

This adds a final touch to the definitive answer, as far as the API v.4.2.x permits in the 2018-Q2.