# Can you get the identity/address of the publisher and subscriber in ZeroMQ?

Tags: c, zeromq

I have been reading the docs and I can't seem to find if there's any information regarding my query.

I just need the IP addresses of the publisher and the subscriber to keep track  and so I can display them as an output of my program.

Assuming I have a network wherein my publisher and subscribers are connected, is it possible for publishers to determine every subscribers' IP address and vice-versa?

So I can have something like this:

```
Publisher of topic "foo":
 192.168.1.1
Subscribers of topic "foo":
 192.168.1.2
 192.168.1.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>**[+1]** for your inspirative motto: " *The day we die is the day we stop learning* "</sup>

> *can have something like this: ?*

### Well,
Yes and No :

While API v4.2+ enables some help for settings that make **`PUB`**-side application code aware of the actually setup/cleanup of individual **`SUB`**-side initiated subscriptions ( using an **`XSUB`** Scalable Formal Communication Pattern Archetype instead of `SUB` ), yet the `PUB/XPUB`-side has to change it's behaviour, so as to process such re-arranged flow of messages.

---

### Identity/Addresses? <sup>( a Human Right for Privacy lost forever ? ... inferior danger )</sup>

This part is harder, there are many transport-classes available, as of 2018-Q2 at least:
these : **`{ inproc:// | ipc:// | tcp:// | pgm:// | epgm:// | vmci:// }`**, so either side would hardly be equipped with some magic-sniffer to detect all above required mappings of soft-knowledge ( the actually valid topic-filter mask ) with the actual transport-class decoder to sniff with. Next, not all connections are easily sniff-able, are they?

---

### Anyway, doable :

In case your application needs to work this way, one may extend the ZeroMQ tools and either equip the ZMTP/RFC'd-protocol decoders, so as to provide your application-side programmes with this low-level piece of information, or the top-level application programmes can self-advertise theirs respective identities

(
yet, notice -- as depicted in **[ [ZeroMQ hierarchy in less than a five seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46620571) ]** Section -- one ZeroMQ-**`Context()`**-instance may have many **`zmq.Socket()`**-instances, each of which may have many-**AccessPoint**-s, each of which may use a different **transport-class** and may get `.bind()/.connect()`-ed to many different remote peer **AccessPoint**-s, so indeed a wild mess of topology morphologies are out there **:o)**
)