# ZeroMQ: a STREAM socket to a DEALER socket proxy

Tags: zeromq

I have the following setup:

```
zmq::proxy( acceptor, clients, nullptr );
```

My **`acceptor`** is a `zmq::socket_type::stream` and
my **`clients`** is a `zmq::socket::type::dealer`.

I am finding when the other end sends a large request (**`~ 16 [kB]`**), the request gets broken up and distributed to my dealer threads in pieces.  One dealer gets the head of the message, others get pieces in the middle.  I am not setting any special options so it seems like this is default zeromq behaviour.

I am using ZeroMQ 4.2.2.

Is there any way to override this behaviour and guarantee a delivery of a complete messages to my dealer threads?

Answer (score 1):

<sup>@namdam deserved [+1] for posting version details</sup>

> *It there any wasy to override this...* ?

### Yes, kindly follow the API documented rules

> A socket of type **`ZMQ_STREAM`** is used to send and receive TCP data from a non-ØMQ peer, when using the **`tcp://`** transport. A **`ZMQ_STREAM`** socket can act as client and/or server, sending and/or receiving TCP data asynchronously.
>
> Compatible peer sockets . . . . . **none**.

So either way, compose the proxy to handle compatible socket-archetypes ( w/o trying to hardwire `ZMQ_STREAM` into any other ZeroMQ native socket-archetype ) i.e. avoid using `ZMQ_STREAM` at all, or create a reading gateway, that decodes and mediates the **`ZMQ_STREAM`** compatible behaviour on one side and interfaces to other ZeroMQ native socket-archtypes on the other side of the gateway-logic.

If in doubts,
 you may enjoy a read into the **main conceptual differences**
sketched in brief in the [ [**ZeroMQ hierarchy in less than a five seconds**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/46620571/3666197) ] **Section**.