# Is there any way to have an asynchronous client and server in ZeroMQ?

Tags: zeromq

Is there any way to have an asynchronous client and server in ZeroMQ, using the same TCP-port and many sockets?

I already tried the **`ROUTER/ROUTER`** pattern, but with no luck.

The plan is to have an asymmetric connection with send and receive patterns among processors. So a `Processor`-entity will be a Client and also be a Server at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is there any way to have an asynchronous client and server in ZeroMQ, using the same TCP-port and many sockets ?*

### Yes, there is.

As a preventive step, in other words, before getting into troubles, best review  the main conceptual differences in [**[ ZeroMQ hierarchy in less than a five seconds ]**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/46620571/3666197) or other posts and discussions here.

The **Yes** above means, **one**-`.bind()`-**many**-`.connect()`-s, which composition still uses a just one `<transport-class>://<a-class-specific-address>`, that for a `tcp://` transport-class on IPv4 means that one **`tcp://A.B.C.D:port#`** occupied for this whole `1:MANY`-sockets-composition.

For obvious reasons, more complex compositions, like **many**-`.bind()`-s-**many**-`.connect()`-s, are possible, where feasible, given both the ZeroMQ infrastructure topology options and also socket-"in-band"-message-routing features are thus setup and used for smart-decisions on actual message-flow mechanics.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your great explanation and fast response! God bless you!

Comment: So, must I use Router-Router pattern or Dealer- Router pattern?

Comment: Without any details, only you know what the { functional, non-functional }-requirements, resources and business-context are, anybody else simply could not see inside your brain, could she/he? Have you read the published API details, best preceded with the indepth Pieter HINTJENS evangelisation of the ZeroMQ zen-of-zero, as published in his book "Code Connected, Volume1"? Definitely worth one's time, if serious into distributed-systems design best practices.