# Communication with a permanent thread handling ZeroMQ with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, zeromq

I have a class that inherits from `QThread` and that handles a ZeroMQ **`SUB`** subscribe socket in a while loop ( polling in the thread's run method ) and notifies the GUI thread by emitting signals when receiving messages from the socket.

In this `QThread` derived class, before the polling loop, I also create a ZeroMQ **`PUB`** publish socket and there are methods to use it. These methods are only used in the main thread ( GUI ) to send data to the server.

This solution works without any problem, but it's not perfect. I want only one thread to handle both subscribe and publish sockets operations. The GUI thread ( main ) instead of calling a `QThread` derived class method, will send a signal to request publishing a data.

Is there a nice pattern, based on Qt tools, to implement that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a QObject, I can use a QTimer to handle subscribe socket's polling and some signal/slots to handle publish socket but also configuring subscribe socket in a thread-safe manner. A QTimer isn't really necessary, I can have ab infinite loop and at each iteration call :

```
QThread::currentThread()->eventDispatcher()->processEvents(QEventLoop::WaitForMoreEvents);
```

to process received signals.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there a nice pattern, based on Qt tools, to implement that ?*

Well,

### ZeroMQ part has no problem to handle both **`PUB`** and **`SUB`** at once

Independently of the primary motivation, the ZeroMQ engine is not the issue here. If looking inside wires and details, ZeroMQ **`Context()`** instances are actually pools-of-threads, which provide lot of opportunities for performance tuning and respective prioritisations, mapping socket-instances onto directly-mapped groups of ZeroMQ I/O-threads.

If not working with ZeroMQ day by day, one may enjoy a 5-seconds read into the main conceptual differences, as sketched in brief in the [ [**ZeroMQ hierarchy in less than a five seconds**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/46620571/3666197) ] Section.

This said, the main concern is on how one would like to require the Qt-ecosystem to "speak" through the ZeroMQ infrastructure. Given a pure non-blocking, well designed code is put into the piping, there would be no major barrier to let ZeroMQ send and collect signals across the platform.

Efficiency of message passing, (ultra)-low-latency and zero-copy mechanics are handy and available at your fingertips. This means, that bad idea or a nasty code will remain being bad or nasty, where the ZeroMQ framework cannot be blamed for "making troubles" **`:o)`**