# ZMQ socket connection timeout

Tags: c++, zeromq

I'm using C++ binding for ZMQ (cppzmq) and I'm trying to set the connection timeout of TCP socket using a `.setsockopt()`-method like this:

```
int connectTimeout = 1000;
socket.setsockopt(ZMQ_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, &connectTimeout, sizeof(connectTimeout));
socket.connect(clientConfiguration.uri);
```

However, I dont see anything (exception thrown?) happening until code reaches actual `.send()/.recv()` on the socket. Just to make sure the socket has a chance to throw I put a sleep between `.connect()` and `.send()` methods.

According to the documentation `.zmq_connect()` just enters a `READY`-state without making actual connection to the endpoint. So the question is when and how I should experience the connection timeout?

Comment: what is your transport?

Comment: TCP, question updated

Comment: I don't see mentions of `zmq_connect` being asynchronous in the docs. Would you mind pointing me to it?

Comment: http://api.zeromq.org/3-2:zmq-connect - "for most transports and socket types the connection is not performed immediately but as needed by ØMQ. Thus a successful call to zmq_connect() does not mean that the connection was or could actually be established. "

Comment: With all due respect, Sir, what is the design-side ( technology ) reason to keep the design under the API **v3.x** given the recent **stable** is ages ahead - somewhere above 4.2.2+ in 2018/Q2? ***( more on this + possible solution vectors of attack below )***

Comment: @user3666197, does it make any difference? does the `zmq_connect` behaves differently here http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-connect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *So the question is **when and how** I should experience the connection timeout ?*

### When ?

Well, actually **never directly** as this is just the API-exposed setting of ZeroMQ **`Context()`**-instances' internal **F**inite-**S**tate-**M**achine modus operandi ( here the `.setsockopt()` sets the selected transport-class behind-the-API-curtain ISO-OSI-L3 details ).

### How<sub>( if at all )</sub> ?

Well, there are some other **`.setsockopt()`** details, that ( if put on ) may indirectly sense the impact of the set `ZMQ_CONNECT_TIMEOUT` connection timeout. Here again, only indirectly, by a modified FSM-behaviour, i.e. in a way, how the `.Context()`-engine instance will happen to respond to such event ( all purely internally, behind the Curtain of API  - that's why we methodologically use the API method for separation of concerns, don't we ? ).

For further details ref.:

- API details about `ZMQ_IMMEDIATE`,
- API details about `ZMQ_RECONNECT_IVL`,
- API details about `ZMQ_RECONNECT_IVL_MAX`.
  <sub>( API versions evolve, be aware that not all [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system) agents share the same ZeroMQ API version. So best remember the Zen-of-Zero and feel free to re-use the anxient designers' directive `#ASSUME NOTHING`. )</sub>

---

### A TRAILER BONUS :

> If not familiar with the ZeroMQ instrumentation, one may find useful this 5-seconds read into the main conceptual differences in the [ **[ZeroMQ hierarchy in less than a five seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46620571)** ] Section,

[image]

<sub>*( [courtesy Martin Sústrik, co-father of both ZeroMQ + nanomsg.](http://250bpm.com/blog:25) Respect! )*</sub>

Comment: Hm... sounds like it doesnt solve my problem of the irresistible desire to be aware of connection problems :) Should I pursue other directions like `zmq_socket_monitor` to get notified of connections problems and such?

Comment: " ***irresistible desire*** " ??? Cool. Doable. Seriously. Just go get it done, simply fork + re-factor the core-lib and you are done, man. Nothing else matters **`:o)`** A similarly motivated effort was spent on **`nanomsg`** the younger ZeroMQ sister, where API got recently extended to have a call to a **`nn_get_statistic( aSock, NN_STAT_CONNECT_ERRORS )`**, which thus seems as an immediate proxy-solution, if you have a design-side option to step forwards to use the **`nanomsg`** instead of ZeroMQ for your distributed-system under-design. >>> https://nanomsg.org/v1.1.4/nn_get_statistic.html

Comment: Great idea, gimme a second I will rewrite the zmq the right way.