# ZeroMQ background thread creation

Tags: c++, multithreading, zeromq

I am trying to understand the threading model of ZeroMQ.

According to their white paper http://zeromq.org/whitepapers:architecture#toc3, each I/O thread that the context is created with maps directly to an OS thread. What I don't understand is why two background threads are spawned by this minimal program:

```
#include <zmq.hpp>

int main() {
    zmq::context_t context{1};
    zmq::socket_t socket(context, ZMQ_SUB);
    socket.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0);
    socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5555");

}
```

As evidenced by the following gdb output, the line that creates the socket spawns two background threads.

```
Breakpoint 3, 0x00007f3cbebfbc80 in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f3cbebfbc80 in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f3cbdff7f7a in do_clone.constprop () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x00007f3cbdff9469 in pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007f3cbf74547d in zmq::thread_t::start(void (*)(void*), void*) () from /lib64/libzmq.so.5
#4  0x00007f3cbf70044a in zmq::ctx_t::start_thread(zmq::thread_t&, void (*)(void*), void*) const () from /lib64/libzmq.so.5
#5  0x00007f3cbf7012c1 in zmq::ctx_t::create_socket(int) () from /lib64/libzmq.so.5
#6  0x0000000000401251 in zmq::socket_t::init (this=0x7ffd5d0323f0, context_=..., type_=2) at /usr/include/zmq.hpp:649
#7  0x00000000004010a1 in zmq::socket_t::socket_t (this=0x7ffd5d0323f0, context_=..., type_=2) at /usr/include/zmq.hpp:463
#8  0x0000000000400e2f in main () at sub.cpp:5
(gdb) c
Continuing.
[New Thread 0x7f3cbc7e6700 (LWP 15499)]

Breakpoint 3, 0x00007f3cbebfbc80 in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f3cbebfbc80 in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f3cbdff7f7a in do_clone.constprop () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x00007f3cbdff9469 in pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007f3cbf74547d in zmq::thread_t::start(void (*)(void*), void*) () from /lib64/libzmq.so.5
#4  0x00007f3cbf70044a in zmq::ctx_t::start_thread(zmq::thread_t&, void (*)(void*), void*) const () from /lib64/libzmq.so.5
#5  0x00007f3cbf70135f in zmq::ctx_t::create_socket(int) () from /lib64/libzmq.so.5
#6  0x0000000000401251 in zmq::socket_t::init (this=0x7ffd5d0323f0, context_=..., type_=2) at /usr/include/zmq.hpp:649
#7  0x00000000004010a1 in zmq::socket_t::socket_t (this=0x7ffd5d0323f0, context_=..., type_=2) at /usr/include/zmq.hpp:463
#8  0x0000000000400e2f in main () at sub.cpp:5
(gdb) c
Continuing.
[New Thread 0x7f3cbbfe5700 (LWP 15500)]

Breakpoint 4, main () at sub.cpp:6
6       socket.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0);
(gdb) info thread
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
  3    Thread 0x7f3cbbfe5700 (LWP 15500) "a" 0x00007f3cbebfc2c3 in epoll_wait () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  2    Thread 0x7f3cbc7e6700 (LWP 15499) "a" 0x00007f3cbebfc2c3 in epoll_wait () from /lib64/libc.so.6
* 1    Thread 0x7f3cbfb4e840 (LWP 15498) "a" main () at sub.cpp:6
(gdb)
```

Using ZeroMQ and cppzmq-devel 4.1.4
Make with: `g++ -std=c++11 -g sub.cpp -lzmq`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***why** two background threads are spawned by this minimal program ?*

<sub>First, [+1] for posting the version details and evidence based argumentation</sub>

ZeroMQ is a broker-less asynchronous messaging infrastructure, built right around the **`Context()`**-instance(s). If not familiar with the ZeroMQ way, one may enjoy this 5-second read about the main conceptual elements in [ **[ZeroMQ hierarchy in less than a five seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46620571)** ] Section.

Given the fact, there is always as chance to define how many IO-threads are to be spawned in a `Context( nIOthreads = 1 )` to be instantiated, lets put it short:

- a zero-IO-thread equipped `Context( 0 )`
   will spawn itself as a thread **`+ 0`** IO-threads, i.e. **1 thread**
- a solo-IO-thread equipped `Context( 1 )`
   will spawn itself as a thread **`+ 1`** IO-thread, i.e. **2 threads**
- a more-IO-threads equipped `Context( N )`
  will spawn itself as a thread **`+ N`** IO-thread, i.e. **1+N threads**

given the experiment above, the real composition in-vivo could get easily validated.

One can easily imagine the role of threads' specialisation inside the `Context()` instance, where transport-class related issues get separated from `Context()`'s main taks, i.e. doing the house-keeping + managing all the FSA(s) / workflow(s) + holding the asynchronous communication services across its local-interface with the application-side code.

In this very same manner, the transport-class **`inproc://`**, having no real transport-related device to control, can work inside an **IO-thread-less** `Context()` instance, where just memory-mapping works across the "borders" with all due local-process memory, yet without a need to operate any IO-thread.

That's a smart and a cool way, how Martin Sústrik et al have defined and finetuned the ZeroMQ architecture. Thanks to them all!