# ZeroMQ: set LINGER=0 does not work as expected

Tags: python, multithreading, message-queue, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm using Python bindings for ZeroMQ. My `libzmq` version is 4.2.5 and my `pyzmq` version is 17.1.2.

I'm trying to let a "producer" transmit a large amount of data to a "consumer". The code of the "producer" is :

```
# producer.py
import zmq
import time
import os

ctx = zmq.Context()
sock = ctx.socket(zmq.PUB)
sock.bind('tcp://*:8000')

x = os.urandom(1000000000) # large amount of data, requires much time to transmit it
sock.send(x)
print('Done')

sock.setsockopt(zmq.LINGER, 0)
sock.close()

t1 = time.time()
ctx.term() # I expect this should return immediately
print(time.time() - t1)
```

And the code of "consumer" is :

```
# consumer.py
import zmq

ctx = zmq.Context()
sock = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)

sock.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')
sock.connect('tcp://localhost:8000')

data = sock.recv()
```

I expect the `ctx.term()` in the `producer.py` should return immediately, since the `LINGER` of the socket is already set to zero. But when I run these codes, the `ctx.term()` does not return immediately as expected. Instead, it takes tens of seconds for that function to return, and all of the large data have been successfully received by the `consumer.py`.

I am trying to figure out why, and I wish someone help me out a little.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Q** : "*ZeroMQ: set `LINGER=0` does not work as expected*"

### ZeroMQ set `LINGER=0` does IMHO work as expected *( as documented )*:

ZeroMQ documentation is clear in stating that all the **`zmq_setsockopt()`** calls ( wrapped, for a use in python, into a method `.setsockopt()` ) take effect, i.e. modify `Socket`-instances' behaviour.

Older versions of ZeroMQ documentation ( being in use in my Projects with ZeroMQ-wrapped distributed systems since v2.x ) were more explicit on this:

> **Caution**: All options, with the exception of `ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE`, `ZMQ_UNSUBSCRIBE`, **`ZMQ_LINGER`**, `ZMQ_ROUTER_MANDATORY` and `ZMQ_XPUB_VERBOSE` only take effect for subsequent socket `bind`/`connects`.

Having this in mind, the `sock.setsockopt( LINGER, 0 )` indeed instructs the `Socket()`-instance **`sock`** not to wait on a respective `<aContextINSTANCE>.term()` until all its attempts to complete all the yet-enqued-only messages get fully propagated to the queue-head-end and there processed into the wireline-protocol and under its supervision being successfully sent or accepted to have been lost on their network-wide way to the neighbouring counterparty.

Yet, this does not say, what is going to be done with the data-in-transit, that the `Context()`-instance is already moving down the wire.

As far as I have [worked extensively](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D) with ZeroMQ since v2.x, nothing IMHO reminds me about a way, how to interrupt an ongoing message transport, using the ZeroMQ semantics exposed to the public API, beyond the `LINGER`-instructed behaviour which might be paraphrased like :
*" IGNORE ANY KNOWN SENDS/RECEIVES THAT STILL WAIT ITS TURN IN QUEUE "*,
yet, this does not stop the progress of sending the data-in-transit down the line.

**ZeroMQ works intentionally this way.**

One might like to read more about ZeroMQ internals [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D) or perhaps to just have a general view from the orbit-high perspective as in ["**ZeroMQ Hierarchy in less than a Five Seconds**"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46615141/how-to-control-the-source-ip-address-of-a-zeromq-packet-on-a-machine-with-multip/46620571#46620571).

---

<sub>**Epilogue** : For Use in a Last Resort Case Only



If indeed in an ultimate need to have some way to stop even these in-transit message flows, feel free to post a new question on how to make things work that wild way.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, [this is still a problem](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/issues/3252)

It can be avoided by setting the linger option at socket create time, rather than right before close.