# PUB/SUB Api doesn't send messages back, what might be the problem?

Tags: javascript, node.js, zeromq, publish-subscribe

I have almost completed pub/sub fake-server, that requests user password and email (from the client), compares this info with database and returns data back. It has 'api_in' and 'api_out' frames and then the JSON. 
The publisher takes and processes all the info without a hitch, but it doesn't seem to send anything back to the client (subscriber) and I don't know why, cause it is connected to the subsequent port.

And I know that this implementation is not a classic PUB/SUB pattern, but that was prerequisite, to do it like that.

I tried different pub/sub options, but nothing has changed.

Server

```
let zmq = require('zeromq');
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

const DBSOURCE = "./db.sqlite";

let db  = new sqlite3.Database(DBSOURCE, (err) => {
    if(err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        throw err;
    } else {
        console.log('Connected to SQLite database');
        db.run(`CREATE TABLE users (
        user_id INTEGER, 
        email TEXT,
        passw TEXT)`,
            (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    // Table already created
                } else {
                    // Creating rows
                    let insert = 'INSERT INTO users (user_id, email, passw) VALUES (?,?,?)';
                    db.run(insert, [123098, 'phillCollins@gmail.com','5502013']);
                    db.run(insert, [42424242,'dukenukem3d@mustdie.com','RodriguesShallLiveLong']);
                    db.run(insert, [5,'yourchick@yandex.ru','semolinaAndPain666']);

                }
            })
    }
});


const args = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));

const pubSocket = zmq.socket('pub', null);

pubSocket.bindSync(`tcp://127.0.0.1:${args['pub']}`);

const subSocket = zmq.socket('sub', null);

subSocket.subscribe('api_in');

subSocket.on('message', function(data) {
    let message = data.toString().replace(/api_in/g, '');
    let mes = JSON.parse(message);

    let api_out = 'api_out';

    let errorWrongPWD = 'WRONG_PWD';
    let errorWrongFormat = 'WRONG_FORMAT';

    if(mes.type = 'login') {
        db.get(`SELECT user_id from users WHERE email = ? and passw = ?`, [mes.email, mes.pwd], function(err, row) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                if(row) {
                    let msg = {
                        msg_id: mes.msg_id,
                        user_id: row.user_id,
                        status: 'ok'
                    }

                    let outMessage = api_out + JSON.stringify(msg);

                    console.log(outMessage);
                    subSocket.send(outMessage);
                } else {
                    let msg = {
                        msg_id: mes.msg_id,
                        status: 'error',
                        error: mes.email == '' || mes.pwd == '' ?  errorWrongFormat : errorWrongPWD
                    }
                    console.log(msg);

                    let outMessage = api_out + JSON.stringify(msg);

                    subSocket.send(outMessage);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});


subSocket.bindSync(`tcp://127.0.0.1:${args['sub']}`);
```

client

```
let zmq = require('zeromq');
let uniqid = require('uniqid');

let readline = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

const args = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));

const pubSocket = zmq.socket('pub', null);

let pubSocketTCP = `tcp://127.0.0.1:${args['sub']}`;

pubSocket.connect(pubSocketTCP);

const subSocket = zmq.socket('sub', null);

let subSocketTCP = `tcp://127.0.0.1:${args['pub']}`;

subSocket.connect(subSocketTCP);



let api_in = 'api_in';
let secondFrame = {
    type: 'login',
    email: '',
    pwd: '',
    msg_id: uniqid()
}

readline.question('What is your email? \n', (email) => {
    secondFrame.email = email;
    readline.question('What is your password \n', (pwd) => {
        secondFrame.pwd = pwd;
        let msg = api_in + JSON.stringify(secondFrame);
        console.log(msg);
        pubSocket.send(msg);
    });
});

subSocket.subscribe('api_out');

subSocket.on('message', (response) => {
/*     let res = response.toString().replace('api_out');
    let responseParsed = JSON.parse(res);
    console.log(responseParsed.status);
    if(response.status == 'error') console.log(response.error); */
    console.log(response);
});
```

I want the server side to send info back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all, welcome to the Zen-of-Zero domain. ZeroMQ is a powerful tool for smart signaling / messaging, so if you pay attention to all its internal beauties, there will be no such thing you will not be able to do with it ( nightmares still not avoided on this way forward ). If feeling to be new to this domain, one may enjoy a short read into ["ZeroMQ **Principles in less than Five Seconds**"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46615141/how-to-control-the-source-ip-address-of-a-zeromq-packet-on-a-machine-with-multip/46620571#46620571) before diving into further details on subject, or re-use some of tricks posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D)

> **Q** : *it doesn't seem to send anything back to the client (subscriber) and I don't know why*

There are two pieces of code, that seem to use both **`PUB`** and **`SUB`** Scalable Formal Communication Pattern Archetypes, yet have some glitches on how these get configured.

---

### The server-code :

seems to try to instantiate **`PUB`**-archetype and equips that instance with a single AccessPoint, using `.bindSync()`-method and cli-parameter `args['pub']` for accepting connections over a plain and common`tcp://`-transport-class.

After defining the event-handler `.on( 'message', ... )` for the second instance, being the **`SUB`**-archetype, this one becomes `.bindSync()`-equipped with a single AccessPoint, using `tcp://`-transport-class, for receiving connections using `tcp://`-transport-class.

If you indeed have to make a `.send()` over a `SUB`-alike archetype, you have to use **`XSUB`** alternative, where you can send data and perform some tricks with the actual  payload on the `PUB`-side or `XPUB`-side ( ref. API documentation for details about `ZMQ_XPUB_MANUAL` mode capabilities and limits for some wilder data-mangling on the `XPUB`-side )

> **`ZMQ_XSUB`**
>
> Same as `ZMQ_SUB` except that you subscribe by sending subscription messages to the socket. Subscription message is a byte 1 (for subscriptions) or byte 0 (for unsubscriptions) followed by the subscription body. Messages without a sub/unsub prefix may also be sent, but have no effect on subscription status.

---

### The client-code :

Seems to instantiate and `.connect()` both the client-local `PUB` and `SUB` Archetypes over `tcp://`-transport-class to the server-side AccessPoints ( which both ought to set ZMQ_LINGER to 0, so as to avoid infinitely hanging orphans ( version dependent defaults do not have other solution but an explicit setting on this ) ).

---

### Possible improvements :

- `XPUB/XSUB` with `ZMQ_XPUB_MANUAL` may solve the sending via **`SUB`**-archetype
- `XPUB/SUB` with `ZMQ_XPUB_MANUAL` may solve the sending via **`SUB`**-archetype with less comfort of masquerading the messages to be sent via the `.subscribe()`-method
- `PUB/SUB` with making all `.send()`-s strictly via a local `PUB`-archetype instance.
- be explicit with `ZMQ_SNDHWM` and `ZMQ_RCVHWM` parameters if still loosing messages
- be explicit on setting `.subscribe()` only after a successfully completed `{ .bind() + .connect() }`-methods ( systematically using original `zmq_errno()` and `zmq_strerror()` functions for actively detecting and repairing the potential colliding states )
- may request to work with only completed connections ( distributed systems have zero-warranty of an order of operations autonomous distributed (many) agents perform ) using `.setsockopt( ZMQ_IMMEDIATE, 1 )`

Answer (score 0):

Your server is trying to send on the sub socket

`subSocket.send(outMessage);`

You can't send on the sub socket. It should be sending on a pub socket.