# pyzmq simultaneous send to multiple clients

Tags: python, networking, raspberry-pi, pyzmq

I have a Raspberry Pi client and 4 Raspberry Pi servers. I want the client to send a string message to all 4 servers simultaneously to capture image. Right now I am using something like the following in sequential order.

```
socket.send(capture)
socket1.send(capture)
socket2.send(capture)
socket3.send(capture)
```

Would changing to something like publish/subscribe model improve how close the clients receive the message? I would like to have the 4 clients get the capture message within 5ms or less of each other.

Comment: You can use the PUB/SUB pattern.
Your client would bind to an IP:PORT and your servers would connect to the client IP:PORT and set an empty string for the filter (pls check the documentation)
The client will then PUBLISH a string. This message is sent to all subscribed servers simultaneously. 
Once the servers receive the message they can start the capture process.

Answer (score 1):

### Welcome to the Zen-of-Zero :

while we get Zero warranties, we may do a few steps here, in a due direction. If new to ZeroMQ, feel free to read a few of the [posts here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D) and at least "[ZeroMQ **Principles in less than Five Seconds**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46615141/how-to-control-the-source-ip-address-of-a-zeromq-packet-on-a-machine-with-multip/46620571#46620571)" before diving into further details :

### CLIENT-code conceptual template :

```
   import zmq;                 print( zmq.zmq_version() ) # INF:

   aCtx = zmq.Context( 4 )                                # request 4-I/O-threads
   aPUB = aCtx.socket( zmq.PUB )                          # PUB-instance
   aPUB.setsockopt(    zmq.LINGER,   0 )                  # avoid deadlock on close
   aPUB.setsockopt(    zmq.SNDBUF, 3 * PayLoadSIZE )      # FullHD ~ 6 MB, 4K ~ ...
   aPUB.setsockopt(    zmq.SNDHWM, aNumOfPicsInQUEUE )    # 1, ~3? ~10?, !1000 ...
   aPUB.setsockopt(    zmq.IMMEDIATE, 1 )                 # ignore L1/L2-incomplete(s)
   aPUB.setsockopt(    zmq.CONFLATE, 1 )                  # do not re-send "old"
   aPUB.bind( <transport-class>:<port#> )                 # tcp:? udp-multicast?
   #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------[RTO]
   # may like to set aPayLOAD = gzip.compress( dill.dumps( capture ), compressionLEVEL )
   #                 yields reduced sizes of the serialised <capture> data
   #                 at costs of about ~30~60 [ms] on either side
   #                 which may lower the network traffic and .SNDBUF-sizing issues
   #----------------------------------------------------------------------
   while <any reason>:
         try:
              aPUB.send( aPayLOAD, zmq.NOBLOCK )
         except:
              # handle as per errno ...
         finally:
              pass
   #----------------------------------------------------------------------
   aPUB.close()
   aCtx.term()
```

### SERVER-code conceptual template :

```
   import zmq;                 print( zmq.zmq_version() ) # INF:

   aCtx = zmq.Context()                                   # request 4-I/O-threads
   aSUB = aCtx.socket( zmq.SUB )                          # SUB-instance
   aSUB.setsockopt(    zmq.LINGER,   0 )                  # avoid deadlock on close
   aSUB.setsockopt(    zmq.RCVBUF, 3 * PayLoadSIZE )      # FullHD ~ 6 MB, 4K ~ ...
   aSUB.setsockopt(    zmq.RCVHWM, aNumOfPicsInQUEUE )    # 1, ~3? ~10?, !1000 ...
   aSUB.setsockopt(    zmq.IMMEDIATE, 1 )                 # ignore L1/L2-incomplete(s)
   aSUB.setsockopt(    zmq.CONFLATE, 1 )                  # do not re-recv "old"
   aSUB.setsockopt(    zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "" )                # do subscribe to whatever comes
   aSUB.connect( <transport-class>:<port#> )              # tcp:? udp-multicast?
   #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------[RTO]
   while <any reason>:
         try:
              if ( aSUB.poll( zmq.POLLIN, 0 ) == 0 ):
                 # nothing in the receiving Queue ready-to-.recv()
                 # sleep()
                 # do some system work etc
              else:
                 aPayLOAD = aSUB.recv( zmq.NOBLOCK )
                 #--------------------------------------------------------
                 # decompress / deserialise the original object
                 # capture = dill.loads( gzip.decompress( aPayLOAD ) )
                 #--------------------------------------------------------
                 # PROCESS THE DATA :
                 # ...
         except: 
              # handle as per errno ...
         finally:
              pass
   #----------------------------------------------------------------------
   aSUB.close()
   aCtx.term()
```

Comment: What does the `zmq.COMPLETE` option do?

Comment: @BenyaminJafari Mea Culpa - the code was typed in a hurry and the idea was faster than my typing skills - the proper option setting to use is the **`zmq.IMMEDIATE`** module constant, which prevents putting the message-payload(s) into queue(s) for L1/L2-incomplete connections ( ZeroMQ ZMTP/RFC-documents are clear on how rich the state-full connection-management is ) thus reasonably avoiding any latency on steps, that are not making sense and may complicate reaching the `<= 5ms` delivery target. Once more, excuse my error.