# Python3 multiprocessing on windows crashes a ZeroMQ code working on Linux

Tags: python-3.x, windows, multiprocessing, zeromq, crash-reports

I'm coding a ZeroMQ-based server which needs to instantiate some workers (defined by their own scripts) with whom I'm communicating through **`multiprocessing.Queue`**-s.

**Basically, I have :** 
- one main class handling all the communication with the other environments in which there is a lot of things, including in particular : 
- a list of workers, each of them getting some instructions through a queue.

**The fun part is :** I need to have several processes able to communicate to these workers in parallel. (let's say, to implement a "safe stop" function for instance)

Everything works perfectly fine on Linux, but I get a lot of issue on windows. In particular I'm getting this error which seems to come from `multiprocessing.spawn.py` :

> `no default __reduce__ due to non-trivial __cinit__`

I reproduced the error with this minimum working code

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import numpy as np
import zmq
import time

class myClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.context = zmq.Context()
        #many zmq stuff
    def foo(self, bar):
        print( bar )
    def run(self):
        while True :
            time.sleep(1)
            a = np.array([1,2,3])
            dico = {"a":a}
            Process(target=self.foo, args=(dico,)).start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = myClass()
    b.run()
```

I've looked it up, and somehow its seems that I need to redefine the context each time I call a "run", which can't be done because I need to send a lot of data through these queues at high speed.

If anyone has a clue on what to do...

Answer (score 0):

> *If anyone has a clue on what to do...*

First, welcome to the domain of Zen-of-Zero

<sub>In case one has never worked with ZeroMQ,
one may here enjoy to first look at ["ZeroMQ **Principles** in less than **Five Seconds**"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46615141/how-to-control-the-source-ip-address-of-a-zeromq-packet-on-a-machine-with-multip/46620571#46620571)
before diving into further details</sub>

If problem appears in Windows only ( not in linux-class O/S-es ) one would suffer a temptation to propose the most straightforward step, not to ...

Yet, I will resist such a temptation and will start with root-cause isolation steps:

Windows-class O/S-es use other form of process-instantiations in **`multiprocessing`**

### The Best Next Step : evaluate your whole code-execution eco-system :

may use the below placed testing-template to add further on your class-related experiments.

The ZeroMQ part is bothering me. Given the **`Context()`**-instance gets created during **`.__init__()`** the `multiprocessing`-spawned-**`Process()`** shall on Win-class O/S-es do a top-down full-copy of the calling-process ( yes, the whole python-interpreter-process, copying all the vars, interpreter's resources' state-full data, ... windows-mandatory **`spawn`**-method ( not any non-win available efficiency of *`fork`*, *`forserver`* available in win ) simply copies everything - Context()-instance included... )

If `Process`-instances remain semi-persistent ( and may remain such for potentially future re-uses ) throughout the life-time of the `__main__`, the `Context()`-instance remains in the state of the pre-spawned `.__init__()`-call and is trying to command a "shared"-Context()-thread replicas ( hidden inside each of the `__main__` process copies ). So far no collision, yet the **`#many zmq stuff`** may cause the problem, as **ZeroMQ `.Socket()`-instances are not thread-safe** ( as if often warned in the API documentation ) **but are also State-Full-entities, so "replicated"-full-copies may easily turn things wreck havoc**

### ToDo : try to document and isolate the problem-evolution -

best by POSACK-reporting (almost)-each line executed, getting down to the very last-line executed & reported before the crash *( the above presented post-mortem Traceback is too ambiguous to decide. `__cinit__` may relate to zillions places, where it did actually fail )*

this template may help doing that:

```
import multiprocessing as mp                                            # file: ~/p/StackOverflow_multiprocessing.py
import time, os, platform, inspect                                      # 

def test_function( i = -1 ):
    pass;                                                                                                  thisframerecord = inspect.stack()[0] # 0 represents this line
    pass;                                                                                                callerframerecord = inspect.stack()[1] # 1 represents line at caller
    pass;                                                                 _INFO_ = inspect.getframeinfo(   thisframerecord[0] )
    pass;                                                               _CALLER_ = inspect.getframeinfo( callerframerecord[0] )
    print( "{0:_>30.10f} ::".format(              time.monotonic() ),
           "PID:{0:} with PPID:{1:} runs".format( os.getpid(), os.getppid() ),
           "{0:}( i = {2:} )-LINE[{1:_>4d}],".format(                     _INFO_.function,   _INFO_.lineno, i ),
           "invoked from {0:}()-LINE[{1:_>4d}]".format(                 _CALLER_.function, _CALLER_.lineno )
            )
    time.sleep( 10 )
    pass;                                                                                                  thisframerecord = inspect.stack()[0] # 0 represents this line
    pass;                                                                 _INFO_ = inspect.getframeinfo(   thisframerecord[0] )                 # 1 represents line at caller
    print( "{0:_>30.10f} ::".format(              time.monotonic() ),
           "PID:{0:} with PPID:{1:} ends".format( os.getpid(), os.getppid() ),
           "{0:}( i = {2:} )-LINE[{1:_>4d}],".format(                     _INFO_.function,   _INFO_.lineno, i )
            )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print( "{0:} cores reported by {1:}".format( mp.cpu_count(), "mp.cpu_count()" ) )
    print( "{0:} cores permit'd by {1:}".format( os.sched_getaffinity(0), "os.sched_getaffinity(0)" ) )
    print( "O/S sub-process instantiation methods {0:} available".format( mp.get_all_start_methods() ) )
    print( "O/S will use this instantiation method {0:}".format( mp.get_start_method() ) )
    print( "{0:_>30.10f} :: will call .Pool()".format( time.monotonic() ) )
    #------mp.Pool()-----------------------------------------------------
    pool = mp.Pool( mp.cpu_count() )
    print( "{0:_>30.10f} :: pool.map() to be called".format( time.monotonic() ) )
    #---.map()--------------------------------------?
    #---.map(                                       ?
    pool.map( test_function, [i for i in range(4) ] )
    #---.map(                                       ?
    #---.map()--------------------------------------?
    print( "{0:_>30.10f} :: pool.map() call RETd".format( time.monotonic() ) )
    pool.close()
    #---.close()
    print( "{0:_>30.10f} :: pool.close()-d".format( time.monotonic() ) )
    pool.join()
    #---.join()
    print( "{0:_>30.10f} :: pool.join()-d".format( time.monotonic()          ) )
    print( "EXECUTED on {0:}".format(              platform.version()        ) )
    print( "USING: python-{0:}:".format(           platform.python_version() ) )
```

---

might look about something like this on linux-class O/S:

```
(py3) Fri Nov 08 14:26:40 :~$ python ~/p/StackOverflow_multiprocessing.py
8 cores reported by mp.cpu_count()
{0, 1, 2, 3} cores permit'd by os.sched_getaffinity(0)
O/S sub-process instantiation methods ['fork', 'spawn', 'forkserver'] available
O/S will use this instantiation method fork
____________1284931.1678911699 :: will call .Pool()
____________1284931.2063829789 :: pool.map() to be called
____________1284931.2383207241 :: PID:15848 with PPID:15847 runs test_function( i = 0 )-LINE[___7], invoked from mapstar()-LINE[__44]
____________1284931.2506985001 :: PID:15849 with PPID:15847 runs test_function( i = 1 )-LINE[___7], invoked from mapstar()-LINE[__44]
____________1284931.2614207701 :: PID:15851 with PPID:15847 runs test_function( i = 2 )-LINE[___7], invoked from mapstar()-LINE[__44]
____________1284931.2671745829 :: PID:15850 with PPID:15847 runs test_function( i = 3 )-LINE[___7], invoked from mapstar()-LINE[__44]
____________1284941.2504994699 :: PID:15848 with PPID:15847 ends test_function( i = 0 )-LINE[__16],
____________1284941.2550825749 :: PID:15849 with PPID:15847 ends test_function( i = 1 )-LINE[__16],
____________1284941.2698363690 :: PID:15851 with PPID:15847 ends test_function( i = 2 )-LINE[__16],
____________1284941.2776791099 :: PID:15850 with PPID:15847 ends test_function( i = 3 )-LINE[__16],
____________1284941.2780045229 :: pool.map() call RETd
____________1284941.2780527000 :: pool.close()-d
____________1284941.3343055181 :: pool.join()-d

EXECUTED on #1 SMP oSname M.m.n-o.p (YYYY-MM-DD)
USING: python-3.5.6:
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It does crash precisely whilst launching Process(...).start(). The function is not even called, the sole fact of starting the process causes the crash.

Maybe I'm not using the right tool. Basically I need to have many processes able to put scripts in the queue of many processes. Maybe I need to start all over again with another lib ? ZeroMQ is only used at a higher level from now on.

Comment: @jpaparone It was my initial impression that ZeroMQ is not the root-cause of the issue. The SER/DES-Pickle phase is my suspect to search further - may read more insights about the Windows troubles with spawn()-method of instantiation sub-processes here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58869967/3666197