# Does multiprocessing copy the object in this scenario?

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import ctypes

class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        shared_array_base = multiprocessing.Array(ctypes.c_double, 100, lock=False)
        self.a = shared_array = np.ctypeslib.as_array(shared_array_base)

    def my_fun(self,i):
        self.a[i] = 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

    t = Test()

    def my_fun_wrapper(i):
        t.my_fun(i)

    with mp.Pool(num_cores) as p:
        p.map(my_fun_wrapper, np.arange(100))

    print(t.a)
```

In the code above, I'm trying to write a code to modify an array, using **`multiprocessing`**. The function **`my_fun()`**, executed in each process, should modify the value for the array **`a[:]`** at index **`i`** which is passed to `my_fun()` as a parameter. With regards to the code above, I would like to know what is being copied.

1) Is anything in the code being copied by each process? I think the object might be but ideally nothing is.

2) Is there a way to get around using a wrapper function `my_fun()` for the object?

Comment: try running the code. if they're being copied, why does the array come back with all 1's? why does this behavior change if you remove the wrapper function and pass `t.my_fun` into the `p.map` directly?

Answer (score 7):

Almost everything in your code is getting copied, except the shared memory you allocated with `multiprocessing.Array`. `multiprocessing` is full of unintuitive, implicit copies.

---

When you spawn a new process in `multiprocessing`, the new process needs its own version of just about everything in the original process. This is handled differently depending on platform and settings, but we can tell you're using "fork" mode, because your code wouldn't work in "spawn" or "forkserver" mode - you'd get an error about the workers not being able to find `my_fun_wrapper`. (Windows only supports "spawn", so we can tell you're not on Windows.)

In "fork" mode, this initial copy is made by using the `fork` system call to ask the OS to essentially copy the whole entire process and everything inside. The memory allocated by `multiprocessing.Array` is sort of "external" and isn't copied, but most other things are. (There's also copy-on-write optimization, but copy-on-write still behaves as if everything was copied, and the optimization doesn't work very well in Python due to refcount updates.)

When you dispatch tasks to worker processes, `multiprocessing` needs to make even more copies. Any arguments, and the callable for the task itself, are objects in the master process, and objects inherently exist in only one process. The workers can't access any of that. They need their own versions. `multiprocessing` handles this second round of copies by pickling the callable and arguments, sending the serialized bytes over interprocess communication, and unpickling the pickles in the worker.

---

When the master pickles `my_fun_wrapper`, the pickle just says "look for the `my_fun_wrapper` function in the `__main__` module", and the workers look up their version of `my_fun_wrapper` to unpickle it. `my_fun_wrapper` looks for a global `t`, and in the workers, that `t` was produced by the fork, and the fork produced a `t` with an array backed by the shared memory you allocated with your original `multiprocessing.Array` call.

On the other hand, if you try to pass `t.my_fun` to `p.map`, then `multiprocessing` has to pickle and unpickle a method object. The resulting pickle doesn't say "look up the `t` global variable and get its `my_fun` method". The pickle says to build a *new* `Test` instance and get *its* `my_fun` method. The pickle doesn't have any instructions in it about using the shared memory you allocated, and the resulting `Test` instance and its array are independent of the original array you wanted to modify.

---

I know of no good way to avoid needing some sort of wrapper function.

Comment: May you enlighten us, **how did you decide what O/S was the O/P using**, when the above posted categorical statements were issued? AFAIK, Windows-class O/S-es have but one process' spawn-method for the `multiprocessing`-based code ( i.e. there is Zero-Degree-of-Freedom for user's choice in this ), whereas Linux-class O/S-es have more than one ( letting a user to opt for a more feasible one, if knowledgeable enough to make such choice, given some further constraints may drive one to do so -like preventing some forms of a prior copy or for using CoW), but O/P did not disclose the O/S, did he?

Comment: @user3666197: The workers wouldn't be able to find `t` or `my_fun_wrapper` if a non-fork start method was in use.

Comment: While this may be an important "technical internality" - **how would you ever make a python interpreter, executed inside a Windows-class operating system, permit or enforce to use a fork-based instantiation method?** Given all the documentation is and always was (since py2.7) explicit in that **there is no other but a spawn() method available in Win-class-O/S-es?** ( not mentioning that O/P has never made any explicit statement, nor any indirect indication about on which sort of O/S(-es) he did test, and/or is willing to deploy the sought-for solution )

Comment: @user3666197: From the fact that the code appears to have actually worked, we can deduce that it was run on a platform that supports `fork`. Otherwise, the question would have looked very different.

Comment: Please, do not take the comments wrong :o) I fully agree with your technical approach, yet I did want you to professionally extend the so far posted answer --- so as to be fully-compliant with the O/P and symmetric in how it reflects the given limitations --- with a part, that would **explicitly confirm a limited validity** of the claimed strategy, as **it will remain functional if and only if** the deployed code will remain **but inside a linux-class O/S and never on a Zero-Degree-of-Freedom of choice, inside a Windows-class one**, won't it?

Comment: Thanks for the thorough expounding. Why can you ignore copy-on-write optimization? That seems like a faulty step when the question specifically asks whether mp copies anything.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov: Yeah, that deserves a bit more elaboration. Answer expanded.

Comment: @user3666197: I've added a bit to the answer to be more explicit about Windows.