# Python3 Multiprocessing, Mac Out Of Application Memory For Linear Search Using 4 Cores

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am writing a program to run a linear search using multiple processes versus using a single process

When I run the following program I wrote, it pops up an error on my Mac it says "Out of Application Memory" and it doesn't even seem to start the first process.

[image: out of memory error]

When running a smaller `nums` array it loads the processes but it's always slower.

Is there something I am missing or doing wrong?

I'm trying to test at scale because at a smaller size of `nums` the performance improvement may not exist due to the overhead with processes.

I am running this on a Apple Macbook Pro M2 Chip with 16 GB of ram and 12 cores

```
import random
import math
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Value
import os

def fastLinearSearch(nums, startIndex, randNumToFind, chunkSize, foundNumber, start_time):
    print('start index: ' + str(startIndex))
    print('chunk size: ' + str(chunkSize))
    if foundNumber == randNumToFind:
        print('done with ' + str(os.getpid()))
        return
    for i in range(startIndex, startIndex + chunkSize):
        if foundNumber == randNumToFind:
            print('done with ' + str(os.getpid()))
            return
        if randNumToFind == nums[i]:
            print('Found number ' + str(randNumToFind))
            print("Took " + str(time.time() - start_time) + " seconds")
            foundNumber = randNumToFind
            print('done with ' + str(os.getpid()))
            return
    print("done and didn't find anything with pid: " + str(os.getpid()))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    nums = []

    print('Generating nums array')
    for i in range(1000000000):
        nums.append(i)
    print('Nums array generated')
    # mix up numbers
    # print("Mixing up numbers...")
    # random.shuffle(nums)
    # print('Mixed up numbers')
    randNum = math.floor(random.random() * len(nums))

    # regular linear search
    print("Linear search for number " + str(randNum))
    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if (nums[i] == randNum):
            print("Found " + str(randNum))
            print("Took " + str(time.time() - start_time) + " seconds")
            break

    # multiprocessing linear search
    print("Fast linear search for number " + str(randNum))
    start_index_1 = 0
    processes_count = 4
    start_index_2 = math.floor(len(nums) / processes_count) * 1
    start_index_3 = math.floor(len(nums) / processes_count) * 2
    start_index_4 = math.floor(len(nums) / processes_count) * 3

    chunkSize = math.floor(len(nums) / processes_count)
    start_time = time.time()
    foundNumber = Value('d', -1)  # start at -1, a change shows it was found
    p1 = Process(target=fastLinearSearch, args=(
        nums, start_index_1, randNum, chunkSize, foundNumber, start_time))
    p2 = Process(target=fastLinearSearch, args=(
        nums, start_index_2, randNum, chunkSize, foundNumber, start_time))
    p3 = Process(target=fastLinearSearch, args=(
        nums, start_index_3, randNum, chunkSize, foundNumber, start_time))
    p4 = Process(target=fastLinearSearch, args=(
        nums, start_index_4, randNum, chunkSize, foundNumber, start_time))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()
```

Comment: maybe quit some applications, instead of merely closing them? No reason to keep Mail or Logic Pro open while you're trying to do some number crunching. Also fire up Activity Monitor to get a better insight into what's using all your memory, the thing you're showing isn't the complete picture (and we don't need that complete picture, but you do).

Comment: ok i can try that. is there an issue with the code?

Comment: Other than `for i in range(1000000000)`? Because that's creating a list of 1,000,000,000 integers, so that's several gigs of memory right there.

Comment: does that list get copied over to each process?

Comment: with small ranges, the linear search always beats the multiprocess approach. but I want to try at scale and see if the linear search would be better at a certain threshold

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58869967/740553, but yes that list gets copied. You're pretty much working at the limit of your 16GB.

Comment: ouch haha, yeah okay then i need to share that list somehow (which is maybe better for multithreading on multiple cores) but idk if python can do that. this is really just a learning exercise in practice

Comment: The linked post literally explains how to do that.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm confused: I can see how the code is allocating a vaste amount of memory, but has the Mac not got a virtual memory system backed by a page file? With today's high speed SSDs, having an application's memory paged out to storage isn't even necessarily a bad thing, especially if it's consumed in a linear fashion by the code. Any idea why does the Mac not simply shrug it's shoulders and get on with it?!

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, Ah, I see that Mac swap files seem to be limited to 100GB max, and are compressed, according to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/207641/how-can-i-increase-the-maximum-allowed-swap-space. That ought to have been sufficient for this, I'd have thought.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new process, the data is also copied, so the memory must be shared.

This can be done by using the shared memory patterns here https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

After using a shared memory array it worked flawlessly with a 1/4 of the memory allocated.

Here is what the shared array creation looks like

```
nums = Array('i', range(10000000))
```

Here is working code

```
import random
import math
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array
import os

def fastLinearSearch(nums, startIndex, randNumToFind, chunkSize, foundNumber, start_time):
    print('start index: ' + str(startIndex))
    print('chunk size: ' + str(chunkSize))
    if foundNumber == randNumToFind:
        print('done with ' + str(os.getpid()))
        return
    for i in range(startIndex, startIndex + chunkSize):
        if foundNumber == randNumToFind:
            print('done with ' + str(os.getpid()))
            return
        if randNumToFind == nums[i]:
            print('Found number ' + str(randNumToFind))
            print("Took " + str(time.time() - start_time) + " seconds")
            foundNumber = randNumToFind
            print('done with ' + str(os.getpid()))
            return
    print("done and didn't find anything with pid: " + str(os.getpid()))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    nums = Array('i', range(10000000))

    print('Generating nums array')
    for i in range(10000000):
        nums[i] = i
    print('Nums array generated')
    #mix up numbers
    print("Mixing up numbers...")
    random.shuffle(nums)
    print('Mixed up numbers')
    randNum = math.floor(random.random() * len(nums))

    # regular linear search
    print("Linear search for number " + str(randNum))
    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if (nums[i] == randNum):
            print("Found " + str(randNum))
            print("Took " + str(time.time() - start_time) + " seconds")
            break

    # multiprocessing linear search
    print("Fast linear search for number " + str(randNum))
    start_index_1 = 0
    processes_count = 4
    start_index_2 = math.floor(len(nums) / processes_count) * 1
    start_index_3 = math.floor(len(nums) / processes_count) * 2
    start_index_4 = math.floor(len(nums) / processes_count) * 3

    chunkSize = math.floor(len(nums) / processes_count)
    start_time = time.time()
    foundNumber = Value('d', -1)  # start at -1, a change shows it was found
    p1 = Process(target=fastLinearSearch, args=(
        nums, start_index_1, randNum, chunkSize, foundNumber, start_time))
    p2 = Process(target=fastLinearSearch, args=(
        nums, start_index_2, randNum, chunkSize, foundNumber, start_time))
    p3 = Process(target=fastLinearSearch, args=(
        nums, start_index_3, randNum, chunkSize, foundNumber, start_time))
    p4 = Process(target=fastLinearSearch, args=(
        nums, start_index_4, randNum, chunkSize, foundNumber, start_time))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()
```