# ZeroMQ PAIR/PAIR connection between Ruby an Python

Tags: python, ruby, zeromq

I want to make a simple connection between a Python program and a Ruby program using ZeroMQ, I am trying to use a PAIR connection, but I have not been able.

This is my code in python (the server):

```
import zmq 
import time 

port = "5553" 
context = zmq.Context() 
socket = context.socket(zmq.PAIR) 
socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port) 

while True: 
    socket.send(b"Server message to client3") 
    print("Enviado mensaje") 
    time.sleep(1)
```

It does not display anything until I connect a client.

This is the code in Ruby (the client)

```rb
require 'ffi-rzmq'
context = ZMQ::Context.new
subscriber = context.socket ZMQ::PAIR
subscriber.connect "tcp://localhost:5553"
loop do
    address = ''
    subscriber.recv_string address
    puts "[#{address}]"
end
```

The ruby script just freezes, it does not print anything, and the python script starts printing `Enviando mensaje`

B.T.W: I am using Python 3.6.9 and Ruby 2.6.5

What is the correct way to connect a zmq `PAIR` between Ruby and Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the Zen of Zero!
<sub>In case one has never worked with ZeroMQ,

one may here enjoy to first look at "[ZeroMQ **Principles** in less than **Five Seconds**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46615141/how-to-control-the-source-ip-address-of-a-zeromq-packet-on-a-machine-with-multip/46620571#46620571)" before diving into further details</sub>

> **Q** : *It does not display anything until I connect a client.*

Sure, it does not, your code imperatively asked to block until a `PAIR/PAIR` delivery channel got happen to become able to deliver a message. As the v4.2+ API defines, the **`.send()`**-method will block during all the duration of a "*mute state*".

> <sub>When a *`ZMQ_PAIR`* socket enters the mute state due to having reached the high water mark for the connected peer, or if no peer is connected, then any *`zmq_send`*(3) operations on the socket shall block until the peer becomes available for sending; messages are not discarded.</sub>

May try non-blocking mode of sending ( always a sign of a good engineering practice to avoid blocking, the more in **[distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing)** ) and better include also `<aSocket>.close()` and `<aContext>.term()` as a rule of thumb ( best with explicit `.setsockopt( zmq.LINGER, 0 )` ) for avoiding hang-ups and as a good engineering practice to explicitly close resources and release them back to the system

```
socket.send( b"Server message #[_{0:_>10d}_] to client3".format( i ), zmq.NOBLOCK )
```

---

Last but not least :

> **Q** : *What is the correct way to connect a zmq `PAIR` between Ruby and Python?*

as the API documentation explains:

> <sub>*`ZMQ_PAIR`* sockets are designed for inter-thread communication across the `zmq_inproc`(7) transport and do **not** implement functionality such as auto-reconnection.</sub>

there is no best way to do this, as Python / Ruby are not a case of inter-thread communications. ZeroMQ has since v2.1+ explicitly warned, that the `PAIR/PAIR` archetype is an ***experimental*** and ought be used only with bearing that in mind.

One may always substitute each such use-case with a tandem of **`PUSH/PULL`**-simplex channels, providing the same comfort with a pair of a `.send()`-only + `.recv()`-only channels.

Comment: I though that `PAIR` was the simplest way to start, I wanted a "Hello world" thing. I will try, `PUSH/PULL` then, thank you