# Why will ZeroMQ PUSH/PULL work, but not PUB/SUB?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, zeromq, publish-subscribe

Environment: NVIDIA-flavored Ubuntu 18.01 on their Jetson development board with their TX2i processor.  ZMQ 4.3.2, utilizing the [cppzmq](https://zeromq.org/languages/cplusplus/) C++ wrapper for ZMQ.

I've got a slew of code running using google protocol buffers with ZeroMQ, and it's all PUSH/PULL, and it works fine except I've got one case that isn't point-to-point, but 1:3.  The correct solution here is to do PUB/SUB, but I cannot get messages through to my subscriber.

I shaved my code down to this simple example.  If I uncomment the `#define` statements, the subscriber gets nothing.  Commented (which compiles as PUSH/PULL instead of PUB/SUB), then the subscriber gets the message as expected.  With the excessive `sleep_for()` times, I would expect the subscriber has ample time to be registered before the publisher performs the send.

EDIT:

Why the try/catch on the subscriber? I was getting an exception early on, and believed it was because the publisher wasn't ready.  This no longer appears to be the case, so it wasn't what I thought it was.

```
// Publisher
#include "/usr/local/include/zmq.hpp"
#include "protobuf_namespace.pb.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>


#define PUB_SUB

int main( void )
{
  zmq::context_t* m_pContext = new zmq::context_t( 1 );

#ifdef PUB_SUB
  zmq::socket_t*  m_pSocket  = new zmq::socket_t( *m_pContext, ZMQ_PUB );
#else
  zmq::socket_t*  m_pSocket  = new zmq::socket_t( *m_pContext, ZMQ_PUSH );
#endif

  std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds( 1 ) );
  //m_pSocket->bind( "tcp://*:53001" );       // using '*' or specific IP doesn't change result
  m_pSocket->bind( "tcp://127.0.0.1:53001" );
  std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds( 1 ) );

  // Send the parameters
  protobuf_namespace::Params params;
  params.set_calibrationdata( protobuf_namespace::CalDataType::CAL_REQUESTED ); // init one value to non-zero
  std::string        params_str = params.SerializeAsString();
  zmq::message_t     zmsg( params_str.size() );

  memcpy( zmsg.data(), params_str.c_str(), params_str.size() );
  m_pSocket->send( zmsg, zmq::send_flags::none );

  std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds( 1 ) );
  m_pSocket->close();
  zmq_ctx_destroy( m_pContext );
}
```

```
// Subscriber - start me first!
#include "/usr/local/include/zmq.hpp"
#include "protobuf_namespace.pb.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PUB_SUB


int main( void )
{
  zmq::context_t* m_pContext = new zmq::context_t( 1 );

#ifdef PUB_SUB
  zmq::socket_t*  m_pSocket  = new zmq::socket_t( *m_pContext, ZMQ_SUB );
  m_pSocket->connect( "tcp://127.0.0.1:53001" );

  int linger = 0;
  zmq_setsockopt( m_pSocket, ZMQ_LINGER, &linger, sizeof( linger ) );
  zmq_setsockopt( m_pSocket, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0 );
#else
  zmq::socket_t*  m_pSocket  = new zmq::socket_t( *m_pContext, ZMQ_PULL );
  m_pSocket->connect( "tcp://127.0.0.1:53001" );
#endif

  protobuf_namespace::Params params;
  zmq::message_t zmsg;
  bool retry = true;

  do {
    try {
      m_pSocket->recv( zmsg, zmq::recv_flags::none );
      retry = false;
      std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds( 1 ) );
    } catch( ... ) { 
      printf("caught\n");
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds( 1 ) );
  } while( retry );

  std::string param_str( static_cast<char*>( zmsg.data() ), zmsg.size() );
  params.ParseFromString( param_str );

  if( params.calibrationdata() == protobuf_namespace::CalDataType::CAL_REQUESTED )
    printf( "CAL_REQUESTED\n" );
  else
    printf( "bad data\n" );


  std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds( 1 ) );
  m_pSocket->close();
  zmq_ctx_destroy( m_pContext );
}
```

Comment: After more experimentation, I have found that if I bypass the cppzmq C++ wrapper around ZMQ, and change the code on the publisher side only I can get messages through.  I'm now convinced there is a bug in the cppzmq wrapper.  As my project is pressed for time I'm using that as the "accepted solution" until I have time for a deeper dive.

Comment: Correction:  SUBSCRIBER side only needs to use the C API.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>In case one has never worked with ZeroMQ,

one may here enjoy to first look at "[ZeroMQ **Principles** in less than **Five Seconds**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46615141/how-to-control-the-source-ip-address-of-a-zeromq-packet-on-a-machine-with-multip/46620571#46620571)"
before diving into further details</sub>

> **Q** : ***Why*** the try/catch on the subscriber?

**Because :
a )** `// Subscriber - start me first!` and yet having the **`PUB`**-side sleeping almost "forever" before doing the `tcp://` transport-class path setup to accept any first `.connect()` in `.bind()`, here preceded by a massive nap ...
`std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds( 1 ) );` and

**b )** the `try`'d `m_pSocket->recv( zmsg, zmq::recv_flags::none );` must by definition throw an exception, as there is no `tcp://` transport-class path setup so far ( as the `PUB`-side has not returned yet from the sleep )

> **Q** : *Why will ZeroMQ PUSH/PULL work but not PUB/SUB?*

Well, **both will**, if designed properly, respecting the published API.

Just remove any blocking `sleep()`-s, preventing the `SUB`-s to join in, making the `.connect()`-s able to success ASAP. Plus perhaps move into a non*blocking form of the `.recv()`-ops ( refactor `try/catch` ), as is common in [distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing) to better reflect the nature of preventively designed  `.poll()`-based or reactive `.recv(..., ZMQ_NOBLOCK )`-based event-handling.

---

### Last, but not least :

ZeroMQ v4+ ( as opposed to v2+ and pre-v3.? API ) was switched to use the **`PUB`**-side message filtering, so a due consideration of subscription management (timing/error-handling/resilience) has to take place either.

In any case of doubt, may integrate a use of ZeroMQ built-in **`socket_monitor`** tools, extending the `Context()`-instance, and trace / inspect each and every event, internal to the `Context()`-instance, well under the published API-events, down to the lowest Level-of-Detail.

Do not hesitate to [read and ask more](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D)

Comment: I removed all of the sleeps, then I put the publisher ```send()``` into a while loop, sending (non-blocking) once per  second. I now start the publisher first, then the subscriber.  My subscriber never receives anything.  I've also copied two C examples onto my platform and they can send simple strings.  At this point I have come to the belief that it is a bug in the cppzmq C++ wrapper for the ZMQ C API.  I'm rewriting now to confirm that suspicion.