# Does ZeroMQ implement total ordered multicast for message delivery?

Tags: zeromq

I came across this document http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all but couldn't find anything regarding totally ordered multicast. How does ZeroMQ order its messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

<sub>In case one has never worked with ZeroMQ,
one may here enjoy to first look at ["ZeroMQ **Principles** in less than **Five Seconds**"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46615141/how-to-control-the-source-ip-address-of-a-zeromq-packet-on-a-machine-with-multip/46620571#46620571)
before diving into further details</sub>

---

> **Q** : *"How **does** ZeroMQ **order** its messages?"*

Welcome to the lands of Zen-of-Zero. ZeroMQ has been designed so as to be ultra-fast, exceptionally smart and not to do a single step beyond what is necessary.

This said, there is, since ever ( and seems to be still un-damaged & valid in 2020/Q2 ), Zero-Warranty for a message to be delivered - i.e. in a symmetrically reflected point of view, users receive a Warranty that any message, that **was delivered** is a binary copy of the originator-side message payload pull stop. No other warranties ( i.e. the very same is thus valid for any *(re)*-**order**-ing ).